# Python+Flask. Как сохранить приложенный в форме файл в две папки?

Tags: python, flask, download

Необходимо чтобы файл сохранялся сразу в два места. Текущий код срабатывает, но работает так что в первой папке все *ок*, а во второй - тот же файл, но *пустой, 0 кб*.
Догадываюсь, что после первого применения функции файл исчезает и сохранять нечего.

Что можно сделать чтобы принимать POST с файлом сразу в две папки?

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, 
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def download():



    if request.method == "POST":
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        dir1 = 'C:/Dir1/'
        dir2 = 'C:/Dir2/'
        f.save(os.path.join(dir1, filename))
        f.save(os.path.join(dir2, filename))

    else:
        return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

В index простейшая форма передающая пост запрос с файлом.

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант сохранения в одну папку, а затем копируете во вторую с помощью os.